# If you translate "individually" with "unuope", how would you translate "collectively" accordingly?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

That is, is there an *-op-* word which expresses the idea "collectively"?

Here are what spontaneously come to my mind (with a link to a page using it [and a quantitive idea of how many page are matching the string according to some web search engine]):

- *ope* ([PIV entry for -op-](http://vortaro.net/?w=estri#ope) [> 42M, but too many false positive])
- *ĉiuope* ([Soneto pri svisaj voĉdonoj](http://www.skorupski.com/sonets/sonet.php?year=2005&month=6&day=5&id=1&lang=eo) [< 10 ])
- *ĉiomope* ([Esperanto sem Mestre](http://esm.brazilo.org/esm/EsM-13.html) [< 10 ] )

Inversely, if *collectively* is translated with *kolektive*, *individually* might probably be better rendered as *individue*.

Finally, it might also probably be relevant to use others similar notions, like *tiue*, *aparte*, *sole*, *malkune* for *individually* and *ĉiue*, *grupe*, *kune* for collectively.

Comment: Note that according to the link for *ĉiomope* (which was edited into the question above after some of the answers were given) *ĉiomope* means "as many as you want at a time." This contrasts to the meaning one might expect based on words like *kiomope* - so it would probably be best to avoid words like *ĉiomope* to avoid confusion. Usually -ope is used with a number.

Comment: It might be good to give some examples of your usage of “individually”. I’m not sure whether “unuope” is really a good translation of that word. I think “individually” has a nuance of ignoring everyone else and thinking about oneself. I think “individue” is an accurate translation of that, whereas “unuope” might better be translated as “one by one” or “one at a time”. I think “plurope” could be good as the opposite of “unuope”, and that might be translated as “in groups of several at time” or something along those lines.

Comment: This appears in an in progress [Esperanto translation of documentation about Perligata](https://beta.wikiversity.org/wiki/Lingua::Romana::Perligata). There, it is used to refer to curly bracket characters, who don't have much individual opinions, to my mind. Actually, in this specific case, *duope* is problably even more relevant. But I keep your *plurope* as a good option for some other context I might accouter, thank you. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be inclined to use "ope", which is also used in some phrases in the Duolingo course:

- "Ili ope uzis la aŭton." They used the car as a group.
- "La virinoj iris ope al la necesejo." The women went in a group to the bathroom.
- "Ĉu vi iris ope al la lago?" Did you go as a group to the lake?

The other options you suggested would probably be mostly understood also, however.

---

Mi emus uzi "ope", kiu ankaŭ estas uzata en kelkaj frazoj en la kurso de Duolingo:

- "Ili ope uzis la aŭton."
- "La virinoj iris ope al la necesejo."
- "Ĉu vi iris ope al la lago?"

La aliaj ebloj, kiujn vi sugestis, verŝajne ankaŭ estus komprenataj, tamen.

Comment: I have provided feedback to the Duolingo Esperanto folks letting them know that "ope" is used incorrectly in the course. I recall that I did this on more than one occasion. To my knowledge the course continues to accept contradictory translations to "ope" -- which is not used in real Esperanto they way it is in the Duolingo course. I received the following from a course admin -- **You suggested “did you go in groups to the lake” as a translation for “Ĉu vi iris ope al la lago?” We now accept this translation.** :)

Comment: Update on my previous comment, I've been informed that the sentences quoted in this answer are not in the new version of the Duolingo course and have been removed intentionally.

Comment: Interesting. Personally I am less concerned about what is common in 'real' Esperanto than about what is, in some official/objective sense, correct. The PIV entry for "ope" does suggest it can be used for "as a group", even if Tekstaro, as you rightly suggested elsewhere in this question, shows that it may not be very common. I would probably not avoid it, but I would be happy to learn about any alternatives that are more common and more readily understood by the general community. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If the distinction between "real Esperanto" and "correct Esperanto" is relevant to the answer, please do elaborate. I'm not sure what you're saying.

Comment: Since below, you were also unsure of whether someone was agreeing or disagreeing, I am starting to suspect I am misunderstanding you somehow. At any event, my interpretation was that you were saying the use of "ope" as meaning "collectively" or "as a group", as it occurs in the Duolingo course, was incorrect because it was not really used as such by Esperantists (as seen, for example, on Tekstaro). I however felt that the amount to which something is used is not the only possible metric, and I prefer to use the official word of, say, PIV, which suggests it might be correct usage.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That clarifies it. In fact, PIV is not in any way "official" and is known to be wrong from time to time. I have never heard the word "ope" used in context, and the fluent speakers I've asked have been unsure about what it would mean. At the very least, it does not make sense to use the Duolingo course as a reference here since the course admins have looked into it and acknowledged that including these sentences in the course was a mistake. My view is that the point of using a language is to be understand, so you'd want to use words that people will actually understand.

Comment: Fair enough, and I agree almost entirely, except perhaps with regards to your final sentence, as my view is slightly different, but yours is very sensible. Since PIV and Duolingo seemed to agree, I was inclined to believe they were correct, but if Duolingo has said otherwise and PIV is sometimes also wrong, then you may well be right that they are not correct in this case.

Answer (score 3):

From PIV:

Kolektiv[e] Prezentant[e]la komunan agadon de pluraj kunigitaj personoj: *kolektiva laboraĵo, verko, protesto, decido*.

I would not recommend any of the three suggestions you listed.

Comment: Also from PIV: *ope. Kolektive, unubloke**. As far as go the context of translation that rose this question, this is fine.

Comment: Are you agreeing with me or disagreeing? I stand by my recommendation here. The Duolingo course authors specifically told me that they introduced words like "ope" based on internal quirks of the Duolingo software, not for linguistic or pedagogic reasons. Consider that there are more references to "ope" in Vincent's answer than there are in the whole Tekstaro. The word simply is not used enough for anybody (even PIV) to have a sense for what it means.(The same thing seems to go for *unubloke*, which is in moderate use but can't be simply replaced by *ope* in all contexts.)

Comment: [Mu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mu#Interjection). Depending on context, *ope* might or might not be enough to suggest the intended idea. Also not that to my mind, *ĉiomope* is stronger than *collectively*, as in the former it imply that **all** the member of the collective body are engaged, while a collective decision might not engage all its member. But that's my opinion.